# Is there any way to find priority less suspended connections in database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005 sp2, There are too many suspended connections in the database when i see it with command *sp_who2*. I want to know how to find the priority of the connections, that are they in use or useless.

Does it harm if i remove the suspended connections?

Is there any possible way to find, please suggest me...

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to remove those connections. They do not cause load.

If you remove them the application that created them will receive an unexpected error. You are likely to cause bugs.

Comment: so what should i do.
its making all application to load very slow. As i remove them, application is fast but as the number of suspended connection increases, my whole application is very slow.